# Alpine.Js - grandTotal

Tags: alpine.js

How can i get the grandTotal using alpine.js

https://codepen.io/zaster/pen/eYWvJMv?editors=1010

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--   <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul x-data="{ rows: ['qty: 0', 'rate: 0', 'total: 0'], grandTotal: 0 }" x-effect="total = qty * rate">
    <template x-for="row in rows">        
        <input x-text="row" type="text" x-model.number="qty" name="qty">
        <input x-text="row" type="text" x-model.number="rate" name="rate">
        <input x-text="row" type="text" x-model.number="total" name="total">
    </template>
    <input type="text" x-model.number="grandTotal" name="grandTotal">
</ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!--   <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
  <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul x-data="{
    rows: [
    {qty: 1, rate: 0, total: 0},
    {qty: 2, rate: 0, total: 0}
    ],
    grandTotal: 0 }">
    <template x-for="row in rows">
        <li x-effect="
            grandTotal -= row.total;
            row.total = row.qty * row.rate;
            grandTotal += row.total;
        ">
            <input type="text" x-model.number="row.qty"  name="qty" />
            <input type="text" x-model.number="row.rate" name="rate" />
            <span x-text="row.total"></span><br/>
        </li>
    </template>
    <span x-text="grandTotal"></span>
</ul>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: excellent! this can also be done using ( x + y ) / 2 ÷;